# css: дочерний квадратный элемент

Tags: css, html, width, height

Подскажите, можно ли только с помощью одного css сделать следующее

чтобы у дочернего элемента ширина была привязана к ширине родительского элемента, а высота была равна ширине?

При это без использования свойств Viewport: vw, vh

```css
.parent {
  width: 75vw;
  background: yellow;
}

.child {
  background: red;
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  height: cal(50%-50%);/* какой-то код, чтобы элемент был квадратным */
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='other'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
:root{
  --num:150px;
}
.items{
  width:var(--num);
  height:200px;
  background:red;
}
.item{
  width:inherit;
  height:var(--num);
  background:blue;
  transform:translate(20px,20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Максим, это новые функции css? IE11 не осилил, хотя Edge и Chrome корректно отработали